# Gap between dropdown menu sub items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have tried to find the solution to my issue in other threads, however, none really address my particular problem, at least at such an amateur level. I would really appreciate some help.

I am having issues with my drop-down menu showing gaps between drop-down items and their sub-elements.

The issue is for the following menu item: Restaurants. The submenu for one of the items displays instantly after hovering on the top level restaurant tab, and there is a huge gap between the submenu that appears.

My CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
#siteWrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}
aside {
  background-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
}
article {
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: green;
}
section {}
/*   TABLE  */

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
/*   END OF TABLE  */

/*   HEADINGS  */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 125%;
}
/*   END OF HEADINGS   */

/* Overall menu area  */

.nav {
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Unordered lists within nav  */

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Unordered lists within nav that have list elements (links)  */

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Hover properties for the top menu links  */

.nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
/* Normal Link properties */

.nav ul li a,
visited {
  color: purple;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Hover links are block */

.nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
/* Drop-down menus properties */

.nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}
/* Drop-downs are blocks */

.nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
/* Padding properties for the hyperlinks */

.nav ul ul li a,
visited {
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}
/* Drop-down hover colours */

.nav ul ul li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.nav ul ul ul {
  min-width: 175px;
  background-color: #ADC9F0;
  margin: -48px 0 0 160px;
}
/*    */

.imageBanner {
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(porsche.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.imageBanner h2 {
  color: #624791;
  text-align: left;
}
.imageBanner img {
  width: 100%;
}
/*    All code below is controlling only the form elements on the website   */

legend {
  font-size: 20px;
}
form {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  height: 700px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #09C;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
input {
  width: 375px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/gif" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="maincopy.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Universal</title>
  <!-- the code below is for the background pattern on the site -->
  <style type='text/css'>
    body {
      background-image: url(128-174.jpg);
      background-repeat: repeat;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="siteWrapper">
    <div class="nav">


      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Index</a>
        </li>
        <li>


          <li><a href="#">Parks</a>
            <!-- Code below: creates a new layer onto the lists -->
            <ul>
              <!-- Code below: makes a dropdown menu for the above menu item -->
              <li><a href="disneyland.html">Disney Land</a>
                <li><a href="universal.html">Universal</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="buschgardens.html">Busch Gardens</a>
                </li>
                <!-- Code below: reverts the following contents of the list to a higher tier -->
            </ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Restaurants</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="logans.html">Logans</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="outback.html">Outback</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Test Restaurant</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
                <li><a href="perkins.html">Perkins</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
              <li>
                <a href="statistics.html">Statistics</a>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <article>
      ARTICLE
    </article>


    <aside>
      <div class="disneyImage1">

    </aside>




    <footer>
      &copy; Billy 2015. Disclaimer: all expressions on this site are strictly personal opinions and preferences and may not actually reflect the locations, businesses, etc. factually.
    </footer>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i didn't quite understand your question so where do you want your test restraunt sub to appear?

Comment: It looks fine to me, but your problem may be because you are using inline elements "<li>", my suggestion is for you to use comment out tags to keep them touching, e.g.: <li>abc</li><!-- --><li>def</li>, this will remove margin issue.

Comment: The test restaurant should appear besides outback, but instead is appearing next to logans. This is now after I have sorted out the margin issues (I think at least). Would really appreciate your help on this one too!

Answer (score 0):

Your code was a bit of a mess with a lot of not closed list-items and lists. That said, you can position the third menu layer with `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`.

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5w9odax/) for my solution.

Cleaned up navigation:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parks</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="disneyland.html">Disney Land</a></li>
        <li><a href="universal.html">Universal</a></li>
        <li><a href="buschgardens.html">Busch Gardens</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="logans.html">Logans</a></li>
        <li><a href="outback.html">Outback</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test Restaurant</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="perkins.html">Perkins</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="statistics.html">Statistics</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS that does the trick:

```
.nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
  min-width: 175px;
  background-color: #ADC9F0;
  position: absolute; /* Positioning the third layer */
  left: 100%; /* Positioning the third layer */
  top: 0; /* Positioning the third layer */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code tweak, however it doesn't fix the sub item appearing before the user hovers over it's parent element. Also, the positioning of it is now undoubtably better, but it does not appear in-line to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've put padding to all sides of all the tags. You should organize your css code to put padding only to the required elements.

You want padding on all sides for anchor tags because your menu wants the spaces above and below. However the sub-items in the menu are also anchor tags and the same styling is applied to them too. Hence the extra gap between the sub-items of menu.

You can create divs with class names and put the required padding to the classes.